# Angularjs splitting into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want my data to be stored in an array but mine is stored in a single array, how to split it into like array. This is how it looks like, im spliting it via "|" but i want to store them into array~

[image]

JS:

```
    {
          $scope.polygonPoints.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
          $scope.polyLineCord.push($scope.polygonPoints[i].split("|"))
               console.log($scope.polygonPoints)
                for (var k= 0; k < $scope.polyLineCord.length; k++) {
                      console.log($scope.polyLineCord)
                      $scope.Lat.push($scope.polyLineCord[k].split(',')[0]);
                      $scope.Lng.push($scope.polyLineCord[k].split(',')[1]);
                      L.marker([$scope.Lat[k], $scope.Lng[k]], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup($scope.apiResult[k].DESCRIPTION).addTo(cities);
         }
    }
```

Sry if the phrasing sounds werid, basically what I want it like "1.309..., 103.844" into array[0] and and "1.30916..., 103.845..." into array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW5QV.png) and so on

Comment: Please, post the actual input JSON structure (as code inside the question, not an image which is not really useful) and the expected output, I mean the JSON you want to get (again as code, not an image) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **es6** features using map for example :

```
$scope.polygonPoints = ["1.3|1.2|1.5", "1.5|2.2"];
$scope.polygonPoints.map(res => res.split('|'));
```

**result**:

```
["1.3", "1.2", "1.5"] // array one
["1.5", "2.2"] // array two
```